# Tracking whether emails are read or not

Tags: html, iframe, tracking, html-email

A company wants a system that can log when a client of theirs opens an email that was sent to them by the company.

I first though't of simply adding (an) image(s) in an html email and tracking when and who requests these images from the server, along with an ID for the particular email and thus be able to determine when the email was read.

But upon further research this does not seem very reliable as it does require the user to display the images and most modern clients disable this until approved by the user.

Are there other, more efficient ways to accomplish this? Perhaps through iFrames?

Also, privacy is of course a concern and the user will be notified that the email is being tracked. Are there other legal or privacy related matters i should be aware of?

Comment: This is frequently attempted by spammers, so most mail clients try to prevent any methods that might work. I'm not a lawyer but common sense says that tracking clients' actions when they have not explicitly agreed to it is, if not illegal, at the very least highly unethical.

Comment: I completely agree, hence if any efficient method for this is found, the client will be notified and asked to confirm whether or not they agree

Answer (score 0):

The way all CRM systems dos it, is excatly by tracking when a 1x1 image is shown.
Theres no other way of doing this. The big issue is the spamfilters that stops anykind of iFrames or ip's.

The downside to this methode is that around 10% of users read an email without showing images first.